# Copy properties between structs

Tags: c#, reflection, struct

Is there a way to compare two instances of two different structs and if there are properties with the exact same name, have them copied from one instance to the other?

For example take the two structs:

```
struct typeA
{
 public byte ID;
 public byte distance;
 public byte time;
}

struct typeB
{
 public byte distance;
 public byte length;
}
```

variables are then created

```
 typeA A;
 typeB B;
```

next some values are assigned

```
 A.ID = 101;
 A.distance = 12;
 A.time = 5;
```

Now I want to compare variable A with B and if there are any properties with the same name (in this case 'distance' exist for both struct) copy them to the other variable.
I don't want to use

```
 B.distance = A.distance
```

as I won't always know the names of the properties.

Does anybody have any ideas? Have only heard of Reflection, is that something to have a look at?

Comment: Please, do not include a languge tag in a title unless it wouldn't made sense without it. Tags serve this purpose.

Comment: Side note - I suggest you to use C# naming guidelines, especially part which relates to [Capitalization Styles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x2dbyw72(v=vs.71).aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you to use mapping tool for this. E.g. [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/) (avalable from NuGet)

```
Mapper.CreateMap<typeA, typeB>();
typeA A = new typeA { ID = 101, distance = 12, time = 5 };
typeB B = new typeB { length = 42 };
// ...
B = Mapper.Map(A, B);
```

With default mapping AutoMapper will map properties which have same names.

You should assign result of mapping back to `B` variable, because structs are value types and they passed by value. So, changes to passed copy of `B` will not affect original `B` variable. Result of code above is variable `B` with values:

```
{
  distance: 12,
  length: 42
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please note, that you are talking about *properties*, but your example code defines *fields* and not properties. Following extension method copies fields:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static void MergeFrom<TSource, TDestination>(this TDestination dest, TSource source)
    {
        var fieldPairs = typeof(TDestination)
            .GetFields()
            .Join(
                typeof(TSource).GetFields(),
                p => p.Name,
                a => a.Name,
                (bp, ap) => new { Source = bp, Destination = ap });
        foreach (var pair in fieldPairs)
        {
            pair.Destination.SetValue(dest, pair.Source.GetValue(source));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should take advantage of the [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/).

Then you could use this in the following way:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<typeA, typeB>();
```

In case you would like to set some additional rules for the mapping process you could do this in the follownig way:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<typeA, typeB>()
   .ForMember(dest => dest.a, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.b));
```