# How to copy fields from one structure to another

Tags: c#

I have several input structures which I need to convert to some other structure so I can pass it to my method.

```
struct Source1
{
    public float x1;
    public float x2;
    public float x3;
}

struct Source2
{
    public float x1;
    public float x3;
    public float x2;
    public float x4;
}

struct Target
{
    public float x1;
    public float x2;
    public float x3;
}
```

I am sure that source structure has required field (type and name is what matters) but that field's offset is unknown. Also source structure might contain some extra fields that I don't need.

How do I copy required fields from source structure to target structure. I need to do it as fast as possible.

In C there is a very simple recipe for that kind of problems.

```
#define COPY(x, y) \
{\
x.x1 = y.x1;\
x.x2 = y.x2;\
x.x3 = y.x3;\
}
```

I was thinking about getting a collection of fields and then get field's value using its name as a key but it looks like slow solution to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a squiz at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/how-to-implement-user-defined-conversions-between-structs .

It details the use of `implicit operators` which are one approach to consider.

Some example code:

```
using System;

namespace Test
{
    struct Source1
    {
        public float x1;
        public float x2;
        public float x3;

        public static implicit operator Target(Source1 value)
        {
            return new Target() { x1 = value.x1, x2 = value.x2, x3 = value.x3 };
        }
    }

    struct Target
    {
        public float x1;
        public float x2;
        public float x3;
    }

    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var source = new Source1() { x1 = 1, x2 = 2, x3 = 3 };
            Target target = source;

            Console.WriteLine(target.x2);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Another alternative is using [AutoMapper](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21930344). *Performance will be slower though.*

Comment: Links die, and dead links serve no one.

Comment: @mjwills: It looks like I would need to write operator for each source structure, right? Let's say I have 5 sources with hundred of fields.

Comment: Check out the last line @walruz .

Comment: @mjwills: thank you, AutoMapper is definitely a possible solution. I am wondering if AutoMapper's work is based on the same 'fields collection' approach.

Comment: AutoMapper's source code is available at https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper .

Comment: @mjwills - Yes, Thank you. There is actually a very nice solution provided by Denis Itskovich

Answer (score 0):

Look at this explicit cast

This is the source struct.

```
 public struct Source
    {
        public int X1;
        public int X2;
    }
```

This is the target.

```
 public struct  Target
    {
        public int Y1;
        public int Y2;
        public int Y3;

        public static explicit operator Target(Source source)
        {
            return new Target
            {
                Y1 = source.X1,
                Y2 = source.X2,
                Y3 = 0
            };
        }

}
```

Converting phase :

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var source = new Source {X1 = 1, X2 = 2};
            var target = (Target) source;
            Console.WriteLine("Y1:{0} ,Y2{1} ,Y3:{2} ",target.Y1,target.Y2,target.Y3);
            Console.Read();
        }
```